# Вызов метода не создавая экземпляра класса

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста вызвать метод закрытия, я понимаю что возможно это просто и для человека с опытом не составит никакого труда, необходимо в `main` после вызова метода `updateImages` закрыть соединение, для этого есть метод `close()`, так как `getImagesDAO()` уже создаёт экземпляр класса, необходимо именно его закрыть после того как метод отработал

```
public class DAOFactory implements DAOFactotyInterface {

Connection connection = null;

public Connection getConnection() throws DAOException {
    //получение соединения
    } return connection;
}

@Override
public ImagesDAO getImagesDAO() throws DAOException {
    return new MySQLImagesDAO(getConnection());




public class MySQLImagesDAO implements ImagesDAO {

private Connection connection = null;
private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

public MySQLImagesDAO(Connection connection) {
    this.connection = connection;
}

private void getPreparedStatement(String sql) throws DAOException {
    if (preparedStatement == null) {
        try {
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DAOException("Get preparedStatment failed.", e);
        }
    }
}
public void updateImages(Images images) throws DAOException {
    //метод update
}
}public void close() throws DAOException {
    //закрытие ps и соединения
}




public class Main {
public static void main (String[] args){
    DAOFactory test = new DAOFactory();
    Images images = new Images();
    images.setIdProfile(1);
    images.setAvatar("testLink");
    images.setId(1);

    try {
        test.getImagesDAO().updateImages(images);
        //close?
    } catch (DAOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: нет, static методов тут нет, необходимо просто вызвать метод close так, чтобы он закрыл уже созданное DAO для выполнения метода update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получите ссылку на экземпляр так же как и когда вызываете другие методы.

```
test.getImagesDAO().close();
```

---

Плюс измените геттер так, чтобы он не создавал каждый раз новый объект

```
public class DAOFactory implements DAOFactotyInterface {

Connection connection = null;

public Connection getConnection() throws DAOException {
    //получение соединения
    } return connection;
}

MySQLImagesDAO instance;

@Override
public ImagesDAO getImagesDAO() throws DAOException {
    if(instance==null)
       { instance = new MySQLImagesDAO(getConnection()) }
    return instance;
} 
}
```

---

**UPD_0:**

Если менять исходный код нельзя, то сделайте так:

```
ImagesDAO instance = test.getImagesDAO();
instance.updateImages(images);
instance.close();
```

Comment: А разве при этом я не создаю опять новый объект и закрываю его сразу же, по сути это второй объект, первый не будет закрыт, поправьте если это не так.

Comment: @PolkovnikJ, а, ну да. Попробуйте вынести ImagesDAO в переменную класса и в getImagesDAO() не создавать каждый раз новый экземпляр, а возвращать один и тот же.

Comment: простите пожалуйста, а можно этот момент как то поподробнее? не совсем ясно как это выполнить в коде.

Comment: @PolkovnikJ, обновил ответ. В приведённом коде getImagesDAO() будет возвращать всегда один и тот же объект

Comment: Плюс измените геттер - немного не ясно, а какой именно?

Comment: @PolkovnikJ, getImagesDAO()

Comment: к сожалению такой вариант решения не приняли, конкретно вот это: test.getImagesDAO().updateImages(images); 
test.getImagesDAO().close();, необходимо именно в main написать так, чтобы для одного созданного экземпляра был вызов двух методов, вариант выше не отработал

Comment: Приведённый код работает ровно так, как вы описываете. Добавьте подробностей того, что именно не так.

Comment: Код который я выложил изменять запретили, необходимо именно метод main переписать так, чтобы к созданному экземпляру можно было применять не один метод как у меня, а несколько, т.е. если я правильно понимаю, необходимо создать экземпляр вызывая test.getImagesDAO(), и присвоить его уже в main, а далее к этому присвоению уже применять методы, возможно я криво пояснил, прошу прощения, но суть такова что надо именно main переписать так, чтобы можно было применять множество методов к одному экземпляру.

Comment: @PolkovnikJ, обновил ответ

Comment: отлично, жаль что не догадался до такого простого решения, спасибо за помощь!